# jQuery:get next value on $.each function when something is true

Tags: jquery, each

I got a foreach($.each) function that checks if the current index of an array is 2, and if it is then i want to alert the value of the 3rd index of that array.

```
 var result = str.substring(n + 1);
    $.each(ids_array, function(index, value) { 
        if(index==2){
            alert(value+3);
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Comment: Can you show us your code?

Comment: You probably have more things in your loop. Else you can avoid the use of `$.each` and do a simple `if (ids_array.length >= 4) alert(ids_array[3]);`

Answer (score 1):

You can do it the following way:

```
var array = [4,5,6,7];

$.each(array, function (i, value) {
  if (i === 2) {
    alert(array[i + 1]);
  }
});
```

That being said, you don't really need jQuery for this. You can do it with ECMAScript 5 functionality `forEach` (not supported in some versions of IE). http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es5/

```
var array = [4,5,6,7];

array.forEach(function (value,i ) {
  if (i === 2) {
    alert(array[i + 1]);
   }
});
```

For those browsers, you can write a polyfill such as the one on MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach

Answer (score 0):

You can use a counter method if the array index is not necessary.

```
var ctr = 1;
$('element').each(function(){
    if(ctr == 2){
     //index 2
    }
    ctr++;

})
```